# Python Django3 - Register form issue after deployment on VPS

Tags: python, django, email, server

I have problem with Register form for project deployed here: http://donation.rogalowski.uk:2052/ . Domain name from cloudflare. VPS host: [www.mikr.us](http://www.mikr.us) with reverse proxy to port 2052 unsecured. Dockerized. After click Załóż konto (Sign up) and filling the form it should send a mail verification, shows error:

```
 Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://donation.rogalowski.uk:2052/register/

Django Version: 3.2.14
Python Version: 3.8.13
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'charity_good_hands_app.apps.CharityGoodHandsAppConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Portfolio_oddam_w_dobre_rece/charity_good_hands_app/views.py", line 382, in post
    send_activation_email(user, request)
  File "/Portfolio_oddam_w_dobre_rece/charity_good_hands_app/views.py", line 324, in send_activation_email
    email.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 62, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 310, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):

Exception Type: gaierror at /register/
Exception Value: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

For tests, debugging turned on.
Registration works fine on localhost. How can I fix this?

Github project: https://github.com/Rogalowski/Portfolio_oddam_w_dobre_rece

views.py

> ```
> def send_activation_email(user, request):
>     current_site = get_current_site(request)
>     email_subject = 'Aktywacja konta na stronie ODDAM W DOBRE RĘCE'
>
>     email_body = render_to_string('auth/activate.html', {
>         'user': user,
>         # 'domain': 'donation.rogalowski.uk:30157',
>         'domain': current_site,
>         'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
>         'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
>     })
>
>     email = EmailMessage(
>         subject=email_subject,
>         body=email_body,
>         from_email=settings.EMAIL_FROM_USER,
>         to=[user.email]
>     )
>     email.send()
>
>
> def activate_user(request, uidb64, token):
>     uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
>     user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
>
>     if user and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
>         user.is_email_verified = True
>         user.is_active = True
>         user.save()
>
>         messages.add_message(
>             request, messages.ERROR, 'Email zweryfikowany poprawnie, możesz się zalogować :)')
>         return redirect('login_view')
>
>     messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,
>                          f'Użytkownik źle zweryfikowany, prawdopodobnie aktywny!')
>     return redirect('register_view')
>
>
> class RegisterView(View):
>     def get(self, request):
>         return render(request, 'register.html')
>
>     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         name = request.POST.get('name')
>         surname = request.POST.get('surname')
>         email = request.POST.get('email')
>         password = request.POST.get('password')
>         password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
>
>         if password == password2:
>             password2 = make_password(password)
>         else:
>             messages.add_message(
>                 request, messages.ERROR, f'Podane hasła różnią się od siebie, spróbuj jeszcze raz!')
>             return render(request, 'register.html')
>         # try :
>         #     np = NumericPasswordValidator()
>         #     np.validate(password)
>         # except ValidationError
>         #     messages.add_message()
>
>         try:
>             user = User.objects.create(
>                 username=email,
>                 first_name=name,
>                 last_name=surname,
>                 email=email,
>                 password=password2,
>                 is_active=False,
>             )
>         except:
>             messages.add_message(
>                 request, messages.ERROR, f'Użytkownik już istnieje, spróbuj jeszcze raz!')
>             return render(request, 'register.html')
>
>         send_activation_email(user, request)
>         return redirect('login_view')
> ```

tokens.py

```
 from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
 import six
 
 
 class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
     def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
         return (
             six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
             six.text_type(user.is_email_verified)
         )
 
 
 account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for Portfolio_oddam_w_dobre_rece project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get(
    'SECRET_KEY')
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1"]
DEBUG = str(os.environ.get('DEBUG')) == "1"

if DEBUG:
    # static ROOT import
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    ALLOWED_HOSTS += [os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS')]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'charity_good_hands_app.apps.CharityGoodHandsAppConfig',
    # 'charity_good_hands_app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',  # staticfiles
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Portfolio_oddam_w_dobre_rece.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'charity_good_hands_app/templates']
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Portfolio_oddam_w_dobre_rece.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST':  os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB_HOST'),
        'NAME':  os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB'),
        'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl-PL'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


AUTH_USER_MODEL = "charity_good_hands_app.User"

LOGIN_URL = 'login_view'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'add_donation_view'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home_index'

# //Should be included in .env

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = str(os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST'))
EMAIL_HOST_USER = str(os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER'))
EMAIL_FROM_USER = str(os.getenv('EMAIL_FROM_USER'))
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = str(os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD'))
```

Comment: Please don't share images of code; see https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Thanks, corrected.
The same issue on secured website app:

Request URL: http://ticketing.rogalowski.uk/register/

gaierror at /register/
[Errno -2] Name or service not known
Request Method: POST
Django Version: 3.0.6
Exception Type: gaierror
Exception Value: 
[Errno -2] Name or service not known
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py in getaddrinfo, line 918
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path: 
['/home/django/Ticketing_System_Project',
 '/home/django/py3-env/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/django/py3-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages']

Comment: `Exception Value: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`  this is a DNS error.  `EMAIL_HOST` may be wrong, or DNS on the VPS may not be configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks I will check. Email Host is correct because on localhost all works ok.